# Merging multiple pdf files without breaking hyperlinks

Tags: pdf, hyperlink, multiple-files

I am trying to merge different pdf files (all produced with latex - but with different document classes) **without breaking the corresponding hyperlinks**.

I have tried the terminal using ghostscript, apple automator, the `\includepdf` option in latex: they all brake the hyperlinks created with hyperref.

Any good suggestion?

EDIT: as this seem to be a common problem, can anyone try to explain/comment on why such apparently simple task is instead rather daunting? What is it that makes it difficult to merge the pdfs and not break the hyperlinks?

Comment: Not sure whether it can combine PDFs, but `qpdf` can at least remove encryption from PDFs without breaking hyperlinks, you might give it a try.

Comment: @Skillmon: this  is quite on topic. There is a package (pax) which tries to solve this, and with luatex it is probably possible to (but needs some coding).

Comment: May be [combine](https://ctan.org/pkg/combine). If classes are quite different (e.g., book and beamer) this is **not** a reasonable option, but otherwise (eg., book and scrbook) probably you can change the class of some document with minor fixings, and then use the `combine` to merge documents in a convenient way (optinal index of the documents, general list of figures, etc.)

Comment: The answers to the question [Cross-reference with `xr` package and final PDF combination?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/512405/118714) might be of interest.

Comment: Take a look at [pdfjam](https://github.com/DavidFirth/pdfjam), most of it's options are just passed along to `pdfpages`, and only documented there. Lots of tweaks available, also keeping hyperlinks (not done by default, though). It is part of TeXlive.

Answer (score 15):

My method uses the `pax` package and its `pdfannotextractor` Perl script (by [Heiko Oberdiek](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/16967/heiko-oberdiek)).

If you want to combine two PDF files (`a.pdf` and `b.pdf`) keeping the PDF annotations (internal and external links are kind of PDF annotations), use the manual or automatic method.

(In case of problems, you can use the `--debug` option of the `pdfannotextractor` script.)

## Manual installation

1. Install the `pax` package from CTAN (or via TeXLive or MikTeX).
2. Download and unzip the  [`PDFBox-0.7.3`](https://sourceforge.net/projects/pdfbox/files/PDFBox/PDFBox-0.7.3/) Java library (an old version of the Apache PDFBox, a Java PDF library).
3. Use `pdfannotextractor` on `a.pdf` and on `b.pdf`:

   ```shell
   CLASSPATH='PDFBox-0.7.3/lib/PDFBox-0.7.3.jar:%CLASSPATH%' pdfannotextractor a.pdf
   CLASSPATH='PDFBox-0.7.3/lib/PDFBox-0.7.3.jar:%CLASSPATH%' pdfannotextractor b.pdf
   ```

   (You get two new files: `a.pax` and `b.pax`)
4. Compile the following document with `pdflatex`:

   ```
   \documentclass{article}
   \usepackage{pax}
   \usepackage{pdfpages}
   \begin{document}
   \includepdf[pages=-]{a.pdf}
   \includepdf[pages=-]{b.pdf}
   \end{document}
   ```

## Automatic installation

The `pdfannotextractor` script can perform the installation itself:

1. Install the `pax` package from CTAN (or via TeXLive or MikTeX).
2. Install automatically the `PDFBox-0.7.3` archive:

   ```shell
   pdfannotextractor --install
   ```
3. Use `pdfannotextractor` on `a.pdf` and on `b.pdf`:

   ```shell
   pdfannotextractor a.pdf
   pdfannotextractor b.pdf
   ```

   (You get two new files: `a.pax` and `b.pax`)
4. Compile the following document with `pdflatex`:

   ```
   \documentclass{article}
   \usepackage{pax}
   \usepackage{pdfpages}
   \begin{document}
   \includepdf[pages=-]{a.pdf}
   \includepdf[pages=-]{b.pdf}
   \end{document}
   ```

Comment: This really looked promising, and I _think_ I got it working with the automatic installation. It seems to retain external web links just fine, but with the `run:` type links (ie, `\href{run:foo.pdf}{My PDF}` to open another .pdf file,`pdfannotextractor` reports `java.lang.Exception: Unsupported link annotation type: Launch` and the output pdf file has just plain text `My PDF` and is not clickable.

Comment: @PeterGrill I use my method to build conference proceedings (from multiple articles). Via `pdfpages`, I can add page numbering, headers and footers. Fortunately, an article never contains `Launch` type links.

Comment: @PeterGrill To link to an other PDF, you can use `\href{foo.pdf}{My PDF}`...

Answer (score 14):

## TLDR

Use

- [pdftk](https://www.pdflabs.com/tools/pdftk-the-pdf-toolkit/) if want a command-line interface,
- [pdfsam](https://pdfsam.org/) if you want  graphical user interface,
- [sejda](https://www.sejda.com/merge-pdf) if you want a web interface.

They are free (as in beer *and* speech) and available for most operating systems.
I have no idea why most tools do not preserve hyper links.

---

## Method

For a list of possible solutions -- that unfortunately do not discuss whenever links are preserved or not, cf. https://stackoverflow.com/q/2507766/2657549.

I'm testing with two copies of the following file, that I named `a.pdf` and `b.pdf`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{bib.bib}
@misc{ex,
  author={Doe, Jack},
  title={An Example}
}
\end{filecontents*}
\usepackage{biblatex}
\addbibresource{bib.bib}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\section{A section}
\label{section}

url: \href{https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/531215/34551}{this post}

reference: \cite{ex}

internal link: \ref{section}

file link: \href{run:a.pdf}{file}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

I combined them into a `tot.pdf` file using the following tools, and tested whenever the url, the reference and the internal links were preserved in both documents or not.

```
+-----------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------+------+-------+-------+------+
|  Software |                                   Command                                  |  url |  ref. |  link | file |
+-----------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------+------+-------+-------+------+
|  convert  | convert a.pdf b.pdf tot.pdf                                                | ✗    | ✗     | ✗     | ✗   |
|  pdfjam   | pdfjam a.pdf b.pdf -o tot.pdf                                              | ✗    | ✗     | ✗     | ✗   |
|  gs       | gs -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -q -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -sOutputFile=tot.pdf a.pdf b.pdf | ✗    | ✗     | ✗     | ✗   |
|  pdfunite | pdfunite a.pdf b.pdf tot.pdf                                               | ✓    | ✗     | ✗     | ✓   |
|  pdftk    | pdftk a.pdf b.pdf cat output tot.pdf                                       | ✓    | ✓     | ✓     | ✓   |
|  pdfsam   | (it's a gui)                                                               | ✓    | ✓     | ✓     | ✓   |
| sejda.com | (it's a website)                                                           | ✓    | ✓     | ✓     | ✓   |
+-----------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------+------+-------+-------+------+
```

(Note that the links to files are not converted to internal anchor if the document that was referenced is being merged. I don't think that this is even feasible without re-writting the LaTeX source code.)

### Versions

- convert: ImageMagick 6.9.10-23 Q16 x86_64 20190101
- pdfjam: This is pdfjam version 3.03.
- gs: GPL Ghostscript 9.27 (2019-04-04)
- pdfunite: version 0.71.0
- pdftk: port to java 3.0.2 a Handy Tool for Manipulating PDF Documents
- pdfsam: PDF Split And Merge Basic Edition 4.0.1
- https://www.sejda.com/merge-pdf does not mention any version, but was tested on 2020/03/04.

### Licences and Pricing

- The "server" version of pdftk (= providing the command-line interface) is available [for most operating systems](https://www.pdflabs.com/tools/pdftk-server/) under the [GPL license](https://www.pdflabs.com/docs/pdftk-license/).
- pdfsam is also [available for most operating systems](https://pdfsam.org/en/download-pdfsam-basic/) and is released under the [GNU Affero General Public License v3 terms](https://pdfsam.org/faq/).
- The [terms of Sejda](https://www.sejda.com/terms) for using its interface seems reasonable, but are quite long. The [java library](https://github.com/torakiki/sejda) is under the [GNU Affero Public License 3.0](https://github.com/torakiki/sejda#license) and an [API](https://www.sejda.com/developers) is even available.

### Other options

Not tested:

- https://github.com/hellerbarde/stapler
- http://qpdf.sourceforge.net/
- https://pdfbox.apache.org/
- https://github.com/stlehmann/pdftools / https://pypi.org/project/pdftools/
- https://pythonhosted.org/PyPDF2/

Comment: Looks like sejda was able to maintain the `run:` type links that I need (ie, `\href{run:foo.pdf}{My PDF}` to open another .pdf file). They have a desktop version so I am trying that.

Comment: @PeterGrill Oh, and if you have control over the source file, then you may want to have a look at the documentation of `hyperref`, the paragraph that starts with "If the final PDF file is going to be merged with another file, …".

Comment: Another consideration should be what happens to the table of content in the pdf, but I guess that's a different question.

Answer (score 1):

There are still a few tools to allow merging pdf files whilst retaining hyperlinks. I retested a few of the more established ones.

Ghostscript (free)

The commands I tested all broke some links (however I may have missed a command that works for you).

PDFSAM / Sejda (freemium) these come in many flavours from the same source.

I had best success using Sejda online 4 files will have internal / external links that work as expected. However note in my limited test the last document say pages 1-5 for arguments sake would now be for example physical 15-19 of the total However they are kept as logical 1-5 so I can jump internally from page3(18) to page2(17) or index 5(19) - contents 1(15) etc I do see the old numbers 1-5 in use which helps.

Pdftk (freemium) also merged well in the free version.
However pages as built similar to above only show the new physical page numbers so it is odd to see a link for page 1 that jumps me to page 15.

In summary are you sure this is the route to go down? since numbering of internal links and page numbers will be all over the place. It makes more sense to include all the files in a main.tex where numbering of pages and links can be controlled.

Answer (score 0):

[PDF-XChange Editor](https://www.tracker-software.com/product/pdf-xchange-editor) seems to do this without any problems. However, it is a "premium feature" and the editor will stamp a notice all over your document when you do it using the free version.