# How do I reference sections in other subfiles?

Tags: cross-referencing, compiling, subfiles, xr

I cannot figure out how in the world I am suppose to reference other sections in subfiles. I have prepared a simple example below:

main

```
\documentclass[12pt,letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{xr}
\usepackage{subfiles}

\begin{document}
\subfile{Afile}
\subfile{Bfile}
\end{document}
```

Afile

```
\documentclass[main.tex]{subfiles}
\begin{document}
\section{Blah Blah}
\label{section: asection}
blah blah blah blah 
\end{document}
```

Bfile

```
\documentclass[main.tex]{subfiles}
\begin{document}
\section{Bo bo boooooo}
\label{section: bsection}
Unlike section \ref{section: asection}.
\end{document}
```

If I compile the main file everything works correctly. I can't figure out how to compile the subfiles separately and get the cross referencing to other subfiles to work. I can get the compiling of the subdocument to work by using to `\externaldocument{Afile}` in the preamble of the bfile but it breaks the compilation of the main file. Is there any way I can get both main and subfile to crossref correctly? If you need more clarification feel free to ask.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The commands which underlie the document-environment are `\document` and `\enddocument`.

When a sub-file is loaded by the main TeX file, the command `\document` is redefined to deliver no tokens: It equals the command `\empty` from the LaTeX 2ε-kernel but unlike the `\empty`-command it is redefined in terms of `\long`.

As long as package-authors/maintainers of the subfiles-package do not decide to change this behavior, you can have LaTeX check within the preambles of your sub-files whether the definition of the command `\document` equals that `\long`-`\empty`-command. If so, the sub-file is loaded from the main TeX file via the `\subfile`-command and `\externaldocument` is not needed. If not so, the sub-file is compiled "standalone" and `\externaldocument` is needed.

Could look like this:

main.tex

```
\documentclass[12pt,letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{xr}
%\usepackage{xr-hyper} % in case of also loading hyperref.
\makeatletter
\newcommand\longempty{}%
\newcommand\DoIfAndOnlyIfStandAlone{%
  \ifx\document\longempty
    \expandafter\@gobble
  \else
    \expandafter\@firstofone
  \fi
}%
\makeatother
\usepackage{subfiles}
\begin{document}
\subfile{Afile}
\subfile{Bfile}
\end{document}
```

Afile.tex

```
\documentclass[main.tex]{subfiles}
\DoIfAndOnlyIfStandAlone{%
  \externaldocument{Bfile}%
}%
\begin{document}
\section{Blah Blah}
\label{section: asection}
blah blah blah blah 
\end{document}
```

Bfile.tex

```
\documentclass[main.tex]{subfiles}
\DoIfAndOnlyIfStandAlone{%
  \externaldocument{Afile}%
}%
\begin{document}
\section{Bo bo boooooo}
\label{section: bsection}
Unlike section \ref{section: asection}.
\end{document}
```

A source of irritation in conjunction with the xr-package/`\externaldocument` not mentioned in the manual of the subfiles-package/documentclass might be LaTeX's `\include`..`\includeonly`-mechanism:

The manual of the subfiles-package says that when using the subfiles-package one shall use the command `\subfileinclude` instead of the command `\include`.

LaTeX does nonetheless for each file that is imported via `\include`/`\subfileinclude` instead of `\input`/`\subfile` create a separate/partial .aux-file whose filename equals the name of the included .tex-file and whose filename-extension is .aux .

Therefore the filename of the .aux-file created during standalone-compilation of a sub-file will be the same as the filename of the partial .aux-file created during compilation of the main TeX file when loading the sub-file in question via `\subfileinclude`.

Thus, when using `\include`/`\subfileinclude` make sure to have the corresponding partial .aux-file that comes from compiling main.tex removed when switching from compiling main.tex to compiling the sub-file in question standalone. Vice versa make sure to have the .aux-file that comes from compiling the sub-file in question standalone removed when switching from compiling the sub-file in question standalone to compiling main.tex.

In case of cross-referencing between different documents, you might be interested in an outline of how cross-referencing is implemented in LaTeX. I tried to explain these things in my answer to the question ["How to prevent reference to enumeration inside new environment?"](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/442118/118714).

Besides this, when cross-referencing between different documents by means of the xr-package/by means of the xr-hyper-package, uniqueness of names of destinations for hyperlinks might be a problem when loading hyperref for also having hyperlinks along with the cross-references. In my answer to the question ["Cross-reference with `xr` package and final PDF combination?"](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/512544/118714) I elaborated on how you can work around such problems when using the dvipdfmx-driver and converting from .dvi to .pdf by means of the dvipdfmx-program (, which is, e.g., the automatized default with TeX-engines based on XeTeX).

Comment: Thank you for your detailed explanation. What are the commands `\@gobble` and `\@firstofone`?

Comment: @AzJ These commands are defined in the LaTeX 2e-kernel. `\@firstofone` just takes an argument and delivers it.  `\@gobble` just takes an argument and doesn't deliver it/does gobble it. ;-)   The command `\makeatletter` turns the character `@` into an ordinary character that is treated like `a` and `b` and `c` etc, so you can use it within macro-names. The command `\makeatother` turns `@` into a non-letter like `!` or `?` so that it cannot be used within macro-names any more.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: @AzJ  When LaTeX gathers an argument for a macro and delivers that argument during macro-expansion, the outermost level of curly braces surrounding the entire argument at the time of gathering (if present ) will be stripped off at the time of delivering.  You can use `\show<control sequence>` in order to have (La)TeX display on the terminal what `<control sequence>`  does. After `\makeatletter` you can use `\show\@gobble` or `\show\@firstofone` in order to have (La)TeX display on the terminal what the command `\@gobble`  respective `\@firstofone` does/is.

Comment: @AzJ Btw: `\expandafter` in front of `\@gobble`/`\@firstofone` serves the purpose of havng LaTeX expand the token `\else` (and thus remove the entire `\else..\fi`-branch respective having LaTeX expand the `\fi` (and thus remove it) bevore expanding `\@gobble`/`\@firstofone`. Without these `\expandafter`, in the if-branch LaTeX would grab the token `\else` as argument for `\@gobble` and in the else-branch LaTeX would grab the token `\fi` as argument for `\@firstofone`. With `\expandafter` these things are removed and `\@gobble`/`\@firstofone` can grab the `{\externaldocument...}`-thingie.

Comment: @AzJ I must correct myself. I said: "The command `\makeatother` turns `@` into a non-letter like `!` or `?` so that it cannot be used within macro-names any more".  This should be: "The command `\makeatother` turns `@` into a non-letter like `!` or `?` so that it cannot be used within **multiletter**-control-sequence-names any more".