# DVI files with modern TeX workflows

Tags: dvi

Out of curiosity, are there any modern TeX workflows that still use `.dvi` files? Or is everything going straight to PDF these days? In other words, can I safely ignore the existence of such things as I update my LaTeX book?

Comment: This is going to depend on your 'pitch': most beginners resources concentrate on PDF routes, but if you want to cover say `tex4ht` or generating SVG images then you need DVI support.

Comment: Re eventual need of .svg: so far, I found `pdf2svg` (e.g., in [Ubuntu](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/focal/man1/pdf2svg.1.html) and [Debian](https://packages.debian.org/sid/pdf2svg)) quite useful.

Comment: Related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/130518/is-the-dvi-format-de-facto-dead

Comment: I don't know if the workflow is to be considered "modern" but sometimes, when I wish to concatenate output-files coming from different .tex-sources, I use .dvi-format and the program dviconcat and then have the concatenated .dvi-file converted to .pdf. This way I circumvent problems with hyperlinks between concatenated documents: pdfLaTeX etc create "fixed destinations" for hyperlinks in case a destination does not exist in a document. If the destination does exist after concatenation of documents, I don't want this. With .dvi-format ...

Comment: ... With .dvi-format you don't get fixed destinations and after simply concatenating via dviconcat things work out. I elaborated on the workflow in my answer to [Cross-reference with `xr` package and final PDF combination?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/512544)  This is a rather exotic scenario and I doubt it needs mentioning in a book for beginners.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

- pstricks still only fully works with dvips.
- xetex is dvi really but hides it by running xdvipdfmx automatically,
- Japanese ptex/uptex make dvi not pdf.
- make4ht uses dvi workflows internally (mostly)

Comment: and we just learned about dvipng ;-)

Comment: Given the above, I think I can safely leave out mention of DVI files from the book. It seems that Tikz has the inline command-driven graphics market sewn up so I'm not planning on covering pstricks (or LaTeX's own picture mode), the XeTeX case is hidden from the user, If it ever gets a Japanese translation, the translator can cover ptex/uptex and make4ht is also has DVI usage abstracted from the user so it can be safely ignored in that case as well.

Comment: Generating SVG (via dvisvgm) is another thing to mention I guess.

Comment: Also, doesn’t XeTeX use a different format that it calls a new version of DVI?

Comment: @Davislor It's still a DVI, just slightly adjusted to use OpenType fonts

Comment: @DonHosek I agree: in https://www.learnlatex.org/en/lesson-01 we only mention PDF quite deliberately. Even if people need DVI 'later', for beginners it's easier to start with a simple workflow

Comment: @DonHosek apart from the great pieces of art created with picture mode: you need some knowledge about it to be able to use the (very modern) shipout/background and shipout/foreground hooks.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer That's beyond the scope of the book. They key is to deliberately choose what to include/exclude.

Comment: @Davislor are you possibly thinking about TeX-XeT which added new opcodes to mark directionality in the DVI output?

Comment: @DonHosek no xetex makes more extensive changes and produces an extended dvi format (with extension xdv by default) but it's still dvi, basically.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer is worried that without picture mode your book will miss things like [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/114847/1090)