# Including a .pdf file into a LaTeX with working hyperlinks

Tags: packages, pdf, pdfpages, hyperlink

I want to add a `.pdf` file to a LaTeX file that I am writing.

I used the package:

```latex
\usepackage{pdfpages}
```

and the command:

```
\includepdf[page={page number}]{filename}
```

It produces exactly the result I want, except that the hyperlinks of the pdf file don't work anymore in the new file. Is there a way to fix this problem? 
(I don't know whether this is important or not, but the pdf file has been created with LaTeX as well).

Any help will be highly apreciated!

Comment: theoretically it is possible to reinsert the annotations. Practically there is imho currently only the pax package which is not really maintained and didn't work for me when I tried it some times ago.

Comment: Related Question: [Merging multiple pdf files without breaking hyperlinks](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/497624/4301).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the pdfpages [documentation](https://osl.ugr.es/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/pdfpages/pdfpages.pdf):

> Links and other interactive features of PDF documents When including
>   pages of a PDF only  the so called content stream of these pages is
>   copied but no links. Up to now there are no TeX-engines (pdfTeX, XeTeX,
>   ...) available that can copy links or other interactive  features of a
>   PDF document, too. Thus, all kinds of links (and annotations) will get
>   lost  during inclusion. (Using \includepdf, \includegraphics, or other
>   low-level commands.)
>
> However, there’s a glimmer of hope. Some links
>   may be extracted and later reinserted by a package called pax which can
>   be downloaded from CTAN.  Have a look at it

Comment: Thanks a lot! I'll take a look at pax