# How to make a text as link in a included pdf

Tags: pdftex, hyperref, pax

I have included a pdf in my pdf generation task. Is it possible to replace texts with clickable texts in my included pdf file. I mean to add link for texts. The pdf which I am going to generate should contain those replaceable clickable texts.
I have array of links extracted from the pdf which i have included. I need to add links for its appropriate texts.

```
 Array( 
[0] => Array(
    [text] => Text 1
    [href] => http://www.example.com
)
[1] => Array
(
    [text] => Text 2
    [href] => http://www.example.com
)
)
```

Comment: What type of links to you want on the page? Links to other places in the document or links to external urls? Are the links already in sample.pdf?

Comment: I need external links (link to other websites)

Comment: And are the links already in sample.pdf?

Comment: Yes, Included file has links. But I am failed to extract those links using **pdfannotextractor** and generate pax files. So I extracted those links and texts in other way. Now I have texts and links as an array. Now I need to add links for those texts. 
I know my work is little bit hard. Please help me to replace it.

Comment: You are making it hard to help you if one has to extract the info one by one. Your question doesn't say anything about an "array of links" and how this look like.

Comment: Related question: [Merging multiple pdf files without breaking hyperlinks](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/497624/4301).

Comment: @UlrikeFischer , sorry for the imcomplete question. here its my array `Array( 
[0] => Array(
    [text] => Text 1
    [href] => http://www.example.com
)
[1] => Array
(
    [text] => Text 2
    [href] => http://www.example.com
)
)`    I need to add links for its appropriate texts.

Comment: Your array doesn't contain the right information, the text is irrelevant, but you need  the coordinates of the annotation rectangle on the page.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer ok. Then what i suppose to have in my array. My question is do pdflatex have commands to replace texts in a included pdf.

Comment: please delete this question from my profile. I got the answer.

Comment: If you have an answer you should add it to help other people with a similar problem.

Comment: I moved with pdfbox. this url helped me alot. [https://bryanwweber.com/writing/personal/2014/04/13/use-pax-to-extract-and-include-links-from-external-pdf-files-in-latex-on-windows/]

Answer (score 1):

If you are going to implement **pdflatex** in your **PHP** application.
for mine it was **codeignitor**.

Step 1: install pdflatex.

Step 2: install pdfannotextractor `$ pdfannotextractor --install` in your terminal

Step 3: `$ pdfannotextractor --version` this will helps to find your PDFAnnotExtractor version in your terminal.

Step 4: But Pdfannotextractor also requires package libpdfbox-java. Otherwise we will get this error **!!! Error: Cannot find PDFBox library!**

Step 5: You can download pdfbox from this link `https://sourceforge.net/projects/pdfbox/files/PDFBox/PDFBox-0.7.3/`

Step 6: Extract the zip file and copy paste the unzipped folder in your application.

Step 7: Follow this code.

```
$file                   =   '/home/rebin/Downloads/file.pdf'; 

$pdflatex               =   '/usr/local/texlive/2016/bin/x86_64-linux/pdflatex';

$pdf_box                =   BASEPATH.'PDFBox-0.7.3/lib/PDFBox-0.7.3.jar';

$template_file          =   'user/join_template.tex';

$new_pdf_filename       =   'new_pdf';

$temp_join_file_path    =   'user/';

shell_exec("CLASSPATH='".$pdf_box.":%CLASSPATH%' pdfannotextractor ".$file);

$doc    =   '\documentclass{article}
        \usepackage{hyperref}
        \usepackage[left=1cm, right=1cm, top=2cm, bottom=2cm]{geometry}
        \usepackage{pdfpages}
        \usepackage{pax}
        \begin{document}
            \includepdf[page=-]{' . $file. '}
        \end{document}';

file_put_contents($template_file, $doc);

shell_exec($pdflatex . ' -output-directory=' . $temp_join_file_path . ' -jobname=' . $new_pdf_filename . ' -interaction=nonstopmode -shell-escape join_template.tex');
```

Your pdf file will be generated without any missing links.