# Include word/pdf files in latex?

Tags: pdf, external-files, msword, attachfile

I was wondering if it is possible to integrate Word (or PDF) files in LaTeX in such a way, that one can still use the hyperlinks provided in that word / pdf.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Hi, since I have no clue how to do this, its hard to provide that. Im moreover looking for the MWE itself. Thanks

Comment: have a look at package [`pdfpages`](https://ctan.org/pkg/pdfpages)

Comment: You can use pax to reinclude the annotations of pdf files. See e.g. https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/534418/how-to-make-a-text-as-link-in-a-included-pdf/534454#534454. It is possible to embed/attach word files to a pdf but they will simply be attachments.

Comment: @AlessandroCuttin `pdfpages` doesn't let you use the hyperlinks of the included pdf.  manuel459: I'm not sure what you want.  `pdfpages` will include the contents of the pdf as new pages in your document (but breaking the hyperlinks).  `attachfile` of the posted answer will allow you to attach an arbitrary file (such as Word), but you won't see the contents.  There is not a way to include the contents of a Word document as new pages in your document without first converting it to something else.

Comment: Does the provided answer solve your problem?

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATE 17 APRIL 2020**

After I wrote my answer, [Heiko Oberdiek](https://ctan.org/author/oberdiek) has release a more advance package, [embedfile](https://ctan.org/pkg/embedfile), offering the same as [attachfile](https://ctan.org/pkg/attachfile), and even more

---

You are looking for [Scott Pakin](https://ctan.org/author/pakin)'s package [attachfile](https://ctan.org/pkg/attachfile). According to the description at [CTAN](https://ctan.org/):

> Starting with PDF 1.3 (Adobe Acrobat 4.0), PDF files can contain file attachments — arbitrary files that a reader can extract, just like attachments to an e-mail message. The attachfile package brings this functionality to pdfLaTeX and provides some additional features not available in Acrobat, such as the ability to use arbitrary LaTeX code for the file icon — including things like \includegraphics, tabular, and mathematics. Settings can be made either globally or on a per-attachment basis. Attachfile makes it easy to attach files and customize their appearance in the enclosing document.

The following code give the enclosed result. Double clicking the tag opens the file in your tex-editor (you have to compile my code, the link in the picture does not work).

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array, threeparttable}
\usepackage{attachfile}


\setlength{\extrarowheight}{2pt}
\renewcommand*{\arraystretch}{1.1}

\begin {document}
\begin{table}
    \centering
    \begin{threeparttable}
    \caption{A caption with lot of interesting information of how to interpret the complicated figures and mathematics in the tabular}
        \begin{tabular*}{0.8\linewidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}@{}c| *{8}{c}@{}}
            Test & $1$ & $2$ & $3$ & $4$ & $5$ & $6$ & \begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}}
$7$ \\ $8$ \\ $9$\end{tabular} & $8$ \\
            \hline
           \hline
           1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
           \hline
           1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0& 0 & 1 \\
           \hline
           1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 \\
           \hline
        \end{tabular*}
    \end{threeparttable}
\end{table}

\attachfile[icon=Tag]{test-table-centering.tex}

\end{document}
```