# Links not clickable when uploading to arxiv

Tags: hyperref, arxiv

I'm uploading an overleaf project to arxiv and everything compiles fine, the pdf document looks exactly as expected, but the references aren't clickable. I've followed all the instructions given here, including:

- Uploading a bbl file.
- Renaming my files to include _renamed at the end and then uploading .aux files
- Removing `\usepackage{hyperref}`

but still, the links don't become active. The actual references are all in place, but they are just text. This is true for citations and references to figures. There's nothing in the arxiv output to indicate any error has occurred. The only warning I get is:

```
) (/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/xr-hyper.sty

Package xr-hyper Warning: Load package `hyperref' after `xr-hyper'.

)
```

I'm using the xr-hyper package to cross-reference my appendix. Interestingly, when I remove the \usepackage{natbib}, then the main body doesn't compile, as it can't run the \citep function, but the appendix then suddenly has links that are clickable.

Log file from arxiv:

```
[verbose]: ~~~~~~~~~~~ Running hpdflatex for the second time ~~~~~~~~
[verbose]: Running: "(export HOME=/tmp PATH=/texlive/2020/bin/arch:/bin; cd /submissions/4895371/ && pdflatex 'preprint_renamed.tex' < /dev/null)" 2>&1
[verbose]: This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.21 (TeX Live 2020) (preloaded format=pdflatex)
restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./preprint_renamed.tex
LaTeX2e <2020-02-02> patch level 5
L3 programming layer <2020-09-06>
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/xr-hyper.sty)
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2019/12/20 v1.4l Standard LaTeX document class
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo))
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/geometry/geometry.sty
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/keyval.sty)
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/iftex/ifvtex.sty
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/iftex/iftex.sty))
(/texlive/2020/texmf-config/tex/latex/latexconfig/geometry.cfg
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/iftex/ifpdf.sty)))
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsfonts/amsfonts.sty)
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsmath.sty
For additional information on amsmath, use the `?' option.
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amstext.sty
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsgen.sty))
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsbsy.sty)
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsopn.sty))
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/inputenc.sty)
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel/babel.sty
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel/babel.def
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel/txtbabel.def))
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel-english/english.ldf))
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/mathtools/mathtools.sty
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tools/calc.sty)
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/mathtools/mhsetup.sty))
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/latexsym.sty)
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/preprint/authblk.sty)
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amscls/amsthm.sty)
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphicx.sty
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphics.sty
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/trig.sty)
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-cfg/graphics.cfg)
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-def/pdftex.def)))
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/color.sty
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-cfg/color.cfg))
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/titlesec/titlesec.sty)
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/hyperref.sty
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/ltxcmds/ltxcmds.sty)
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pdftexcmds/pdftexcmds.sty
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/infwarerr/infwarerr.sty))
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/kvsetkeys/kvsetkeys.sty)
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/kvdefinekeys/kvdefinekeys.sty)
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pdfescape/pdfescape.sty)
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hycolor/hycolor.sty)
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/letltxmacro/letltxmacro.sty)
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/auxhook/auxhook.sty)
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/kvoptions/kvoptions.sty)
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/pd1enc.def)
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/intcalc/intcalc.sty)
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/etexcmds/etexcmds.sty)
(/texlive/2020/texmf-config/tex/latex/latexconfig/hyperref.cfg)
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/url/url.sty)
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/bitset/bitset.sty
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/bigintcalc/bigintcalc.sty))
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/atbegshi/atbegshi.sty))
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/hpdftex.def
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/atveryend/atveryend.sty)
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/rerunfilecheck/rerunfilecheck.sty
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/uniquecounter/uniquecounter.sty)))
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsfonts/amssymb.sty)
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/natbib/natbib.sty)
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/algorithmicx/algpseudocode.sty
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/ifthen.sty)
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/algorithmicx/algorithmicx.sty
Document Style algorithmicx 1.2 - a greatly improved `algorithmic' style
)
Document Style - pseudocode environments for use with the `algorithmicx' style
) (/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/algorithms/algorithm.sty
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/float/float.sty))
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tools/tabularx.sty
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tools/array.sty))
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/multirow/multirow.sty)
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/caption/subcaption.sty
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/caption/caption.sty
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/caption/caption3.sty)))
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/wrapfig/wrapfig.sty)
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/sttools/stfloats.sty)
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/bbm-macros/bbm.sty)
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/xcolor/xcolor.sty
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-cfg/color.cfg)
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/colortbl/colortbl.sty)
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/dvipsnam.def))
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/booktabs/booktabs.sty)
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/makecell/makecell.sty)
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/diagbox/diagbox.sty
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pict2e/pict2e.sty
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pict2e/pict2e.cfg)
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pict2e/p2e-pdftex.def)))
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/adjustbox/adjustbox.sty
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/xkeyval/xkeyval.sty
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xkeyval/xkeyval.tex
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xkeyval/xkvutils.tex)))
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/adjustbox/adjcalc.sty)
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/adjustbox/trimclip.sty
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/collectbox/collectbox.sty)
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/adjustbox/tc-pdftex.def))
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/ifoddpage/ifoddpage.sty)
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/varwidth/varwidth.sty))
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tools/afterpage.sty)
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pdflscape/pdflscape.sty
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/lscape.sty))
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/footmisc/footmisc.sty

LaTeX Warning: Command \@footnotemark has changed.
Check if current package is valid.

)
(z_appendix.tex)
No file z_appendix.tex.
(z_appendix.aux)
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3backend/l3backend-pdftex.def)
(./preprint_renamed.aux)
*geometry* detected driver: pdftex
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/context/base/mkii/supp-pdf.mkii
[Loading MPS to PDF converter (version 2006.09.02).]
) (/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/epstopdf-pkg/epstopdf-base.sty
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/grfext/grfext.sty)
(/texlive/2020/texmf-config/tex/latex/latexconfig/epstopdf-sys.cfg))
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/nameref.sty
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/refcount/refcount.sty)
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/gettitlestring/gettitlestring.sty))
(./preprint_renamed.out) (./preprint_renamed.out) (./intro_v1.tex
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsfonts/umsa.fd)
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsfonts/umsb.fd)
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/ulasy.fd) [1{/texlive/2020/texmf-var/f
onts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map}]) [2] [3 <./images/fig3.png (PNG copy)> <./
images/fig4.png (PNG copy)> <./images/fig5.png (PNG copy)>] [4] [5] [6]
[7] [8 <./images/sequences.pdf>] [9 <./images/fig4.pdf> <./
images/fig5.pdf>] [10 <./images/fig6.pdf>] [11 <./images/fig4v2.pdf>]
Overfull \hbox (11.60017pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 445--459
[][]
[12 <./imagesfig6.pdf>] [13 <./images/fig1.pdf>] [14] [15 <./images/fig8.pdf>]
Overfull \hbox (3.79457pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 569--581
[][]
[16] [17 <./images/fig7.pdf>] [18 <./images/fig_v2.pdf>] (./preprint_renamed.bbl [19] [20] [21]) [22]
(./preprint_renamed.aux) )
(see the transcript file for additional information){/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/f
onts/enc/dvips/cm-super/cm-super-ts1.enc}</texlive/2020/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/
public/amsfonts/cm/cmbx10.pfb></texlive/2020/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsf
onts/cm/cmbx12.pfb></texlive/2020/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmb
x7.pfb></texlive/2020/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmbx8.pfb></tex
live/2020/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmbx9.pfb></texlive/2020/te
xmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmex10.pfb></texlive/2020/texmf-dist/fo
nts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmmi10.pfb></texlive/2020/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/p
ublic/amsfonts/cm/cmmi5.pfb></texlive/2020/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfon
ts/cm/cmmi6.pfb></texlive/2020/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmmi7.
pfb></texlive/2020/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmmi8.pfb></texliv
e/2020/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmmi9.pfb></texlive/2020/texmf
-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmmib10.pfb></texlive/2020/texmf-dist/font
s/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmr10.pfb></texlive/2020/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/publ
ic/amsfonts/cm/cmr12.pfb></texlive/2020/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/
cm/cmr17.pfb></texlive/2020/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmr5.pfb>
</texlive/2020/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmr6.pfb></texlive/202
0/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmr7.pfb></texlive/2020/texmf-dist/
fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmr8.pfb></texlive/2020/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/p
ublic/amsfonts/cm/cmr9.pfb></texlive/2020/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfont
s/cm/cmsy10.pfb></texlive/2020/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmsy5.
pfb></texlive/2020/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmsy6.pfb></texliv
e/2020/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmsy7.pfb></texlive/2020/texmf
-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmsy8.pfb></texlive/2020/texmf-dist/fonts/
type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmsy9.pfb></texlive/2020/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public
/amsfonts/cm/cmti10.pfb></texlive/2020/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/c
m/cmti7.pfb></texlive/2020/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmti9.pfb>
</texlive/2020/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmtt10.pfb></texlive/2
020/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmtt8.pfb></texlive/2020/texmf-di
st/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmtt9.pfb></texlive/2020/texmf-dist/fonts/typ
e1/public/amsfonts/symbols/msbm10.pfb></texlive/2020/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/pub
lic/amsfonts/symbols/msbm7.pfb></texlive/2020/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/cm-
super/sfrm1000.pfb>
Output written on preprint_renamed.pdf (22 pages, 748871 bytes).
Transcript written on preprint_renamed.log.

[verbose]: WARNING: Supplemental 'rerun' check detected need for extra pass.
[verbose]: ~~~~~~~~~~~ Running hpdflatex for the second time ~~~~~~~~
[verbose]: Running: "(export HOME=/tmp PATH=/texlive/2020/bin/arch:/bin; cd /submissions/4895371/ && pdflatex 'xxxpdfpages.tex' < /dev/null)" 2>&1
[verbose]: This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.21 (TeX Live 2020) (preloaded format=pdflatex)
restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./xxxpdfpages.tex
LaTeX2e <2020-02-02> patch level 5
L3 programming layer <2020-09-06>
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2019/12/20 v1.4l Standard LaTeX document class
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo))
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pdfpages/pdfpages.sty
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/ifthen.sty)
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tools/calc.sty)
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/eso-pic/eso-pic.sty
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/atbegshi/atbegshi.sty
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/infwarerr/infwarerr.sty)
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/ltxcmds/ltxcmds.sty)
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/iftex/iftex.sty))
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/keyval.sty)
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/xcolor/xcolor.sty
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-cfg/color.cfg)
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-def/pdftex.def)))
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphicx.sty
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphics.sty
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/trig.sty)
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-cfg/graphics.cfg)))
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pdfpages/pppdftex.def))
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/hyperref.sty
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pdftexcmds/pdftexcmds.sty)
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/kvsetkeys/kvsetkeys.sty)
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/kvdefinekeys/kvdefinekeys.sty)
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pdfescape/pdfescape.sty)
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hycolor/hycolor.sty)
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/letltxmacro/letltxmacro.sty)
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/auxhook/auxhook.sty)
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/kvoptions/kvoptions.sty)
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/pd1enc.def)
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/intcalc/intcalc.sty)
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/etexcmds/etexcmds.sty)
(/texlive/2020/texmf-config/tex/latex/latexconfig/hyperref.cfg)
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/url/url.sty)
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/bitset/bitset.sty
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/bigintcalc/bigintcalc.sty)))
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/hpdftex.def
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/atveryend/atveryend.sty)
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/rerunfilecheck/rerunfilecheck.sty
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/uniquecounter/uniquecounter.sty)))
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3backend/l3backend-pdftex.def)
(./xxxpdfpages.aux)
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/context/base/mkii/supp-pdf.mkii
[Loading MPS to PDF converter (version 2006.09.02).]
) (/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/epstopdf-pkg/epstopdf-base.sty
(/texlive/2020/texmf-config/tex/latex/latexconfig/epstopdf-sys.cfg))
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pdflscape/pdflscape.sty
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/lscape.sty))
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/nameref.sty
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/refcount/refcount.sty)
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/gettitlestring/gettitlestring.sty))
(./xxxpdfpages.out) (./xxxpdfpages.out) [1 <./preprint_renamed.pdf{/texlive/202
0/texmf-var/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map}>] [2 <./preprint_renamed.pdf>]
[3 <./preprint_renamed.pdf>] [4 <./preprint_renamed.pdf>] [5 <./preprint_rename
d.pdf>] [6 <./preprint_renamed.pdf>] [7 <./preprint_renamed.pdf>] [8 <./preprin
t_renamed.pdf>] [9 <./preprint_renamed.pdf>] [10 <./preprint_renamed.pdf>]
[11 <./preprint_renamed.pdf>] [12 <./preprint_renamed.pdf>] [13 <./preprint_ren
amed.pdf>] [14 <./preprint_renamed.pdf>] [15 <./preprint_renamed.pdf>] [16 <./p
reprint_renamed.pdf>] [17 <./preprint_renamed.pdf>] [18 <./preprint_renamed.pdf
>] [19 <./preprint_renamed.pdf>] [20 <./preprint_renamed.pdf>] [21 <./preprint_
renamed.pdf>] [22 <./preprint_renamed.pdf>] [23 <./z_appendix_renamed.pdf>]
[24 <./z_appendix_renamed.pdf>] [25 <./z_appendix_renamed.pdf>] [26 <./z_append
ix_renamed.pdf>] [27 <./z_appendix_renamed.pdf>] [28 <./z_appendix_renamed.pdf>
] [29 <./z_appendix_renamed.pdf>] [30 <./z_appendix_renamed.pdf>] [31 <./z_appe
ndix_renamed.pdf>] [32 <./z_appendix_renamed.pdf>] [33 <./z_appendix_renamed.pd
f>] [34 <./z_appendix_renamed.pdf>] [35 <./z_appendix_renamed.pdf>] [36 <./z_ap
pendix_renamed.pdf>] [37 <./z_appendix_renamed.pdf>] [38 <./z_appendix_renamed.
pdf>] [39 <./z_appendix_renamed.pdf>] [40 <./z_appendix_renamed.pdf>] [41 <./z_
appendix_renamed.pdf>] [42 <./z_appendix_renamed.pdf>] [43 <./z_appendix_rename
d.pdf>] [44 <./z_appendix_renamed.pdf>] (./xxxpdfpages.aux) )</texlive/2020/tex
mf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmbx10.pfb></texlive/2020/texmf-dist/fon
ts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmbx12.pfb></texlive/2020/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/pu
blic/amsfonts/cm/cmbx7.pfb></texlive/2020/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfont
s/cm/cmbx8.pfb></texlive/2020/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmbx9.p
fb></texlive/2020/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmbxti10.pfb></texl
ive/2020/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmex10.pfb></texlive/2020/te
xmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmmi10.pfb></texlive/2020/texmf-dist/fo
nts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmmi5.pfb></texlive/2020/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/pu
blic/amsfonts/cm/cmmi6.pfb></texlive/2020/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfont
s/cm/cmmi7.pfb></texlive/2020/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmmi8.p
fb></texlive/2020/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmmi9.pfb></texlive
/2020/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmmib10.pfb></texlive/2020/texm
f-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmr10.pfb></texlive/2020/texmf-dist/fonts
/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmr12.pfb></texlive/2020/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/publi
c/amsfonts/cm/cmr17.pfb></texlive/2020/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/c
m/cmr5.pfb></texlive/2020/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmr6.pfb></
texlive/2020/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmr7.pfb></texlive/2020/
texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmr8.pfb></texlive/2020/texmf-dist/fo
nts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmr9.pfb></texlive/2020/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/pub
lic/amsfonts/cm/cmsy10.pfb></texlive/2020/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfont
s/cm/cmsy5.pfb></texlive/2020/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmsy6.p
fb></texlive/2020/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmsy7.pfb></texlive
/2020/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmsy8.pfb></texlive/2020/texmf-
dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmsy9.pfb></texlive/2020/texmf-dist/fonts/t
ype1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmti10.pfb></texlive/2020/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public
/amsfonts/cm/cmti7.pfb></texlive/2020/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm
/cmti9.pfb></texlive/2020/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmtt10.pfb>
</texlive/2020/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmtt8.pfb></texlive/20
20/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmtt9.pfb></texlive/2020/texmf-dis
t/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/symbols/msam7.pfb></texlive/2020/texmf-dist/fonts
/type1/public/amsfonts/symbols/msbm10.pfb></texlive/2020/texmf-dist/fonts/type1
/public/amsfonts/symbols/msbm7.pfb></texlive/2020/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public
/cm-super/sfrm1000.pfb>
Output written on xxxpdfpages.pdf (44 pages, 1074799 bytes).
Transcript written on xxxpdfpages.log.
```

My latex set-up:

```
\RequirePackage{xr-hyper}
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsfonts} 
\usepackage{amsmath} 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel} 
\usepackage{mathtools} 
\usepackage{latexsym}
\usepackage{authblk}
\usepackage{amsthm}
% \excludecomment{proof}
%\usepackage[notref, notcite]{showkeys}
\usepackage{graphicx, color}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\subsection}[runin]
{\normalfont\bfseries}{\thesubsection}{.5em}{}
\titleformat{\subsubsection}[runin]
{\normalfont\itshape}{\thesubsubsection}{.5em}{}
\theoremstyle{plain}
\newtheorem{definition}{Definition}
%
\newtheorem{remark}{Remark}

\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage[round]{natbib} 

\newcommand{\al}{\alpha} 
\newcommand{\te}{\theta} 
\newcommand{\RR}{\mathbb{R}}
\newcommand{\cN}{\mathcal{N}}
\newcommand{\cP}{\mathcal{P}}
\newcommand{\given}{\,|\,}
\definecolor{blendedblue}{rgb}{0.2,0.2,0.7}
\newcommand{\sbl}[1]{{\color{blendedblue}{#1}}}
\newcommand{\gre}[1]{{\color{green}{#1}}}
\newcommand{\bl}[1]{\textcolor[rgb]{0.00,0.00,1.00}{#1}}
\newcommand{\ve}[1]{\textcolor[rgb]{0.00,1.00,0.00}{#1}}
\newcommand{\gris}[1]{\textcolor[RGB]{136,152,206}{#1}}
\newcommand{\ora}[1]{\textcolor[rgb]{1.00,0.50,0.00}{#1}}
\newcommand{\re}[1]{{\color{red}{#1}}}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}
\usepackage{algorithm,tabularx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\DeclareMathOperator*{\argmax}{arg\,max}
\DeclareMathOperator*{\argmin}{arg\,min}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{stfloats}
\newtheorem{problem}{Problem}
\usepackage{bbm}
\usepackage[dvipsnames,table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}
\newtheorem{corollary}[theorem]{Corollary}
\newtheorem{proposition}{Proposition}
\newtheorem{lemma}{Lemma}
\usepackage{booktabs} 
\definecolor{lightgray}{gray}{0.92}
\usepackage[font=small,labelfont=bf,width=0.85\textwidth]{caption}
\usepackage{multirow, makecell}
\usepackage{diagbox}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\captionsetup[figure]{labelfont={bf},name={Fig.},labelsep=period}
\usepackage{afterpage}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage[multiple]{footmisc}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\multiline}[1]{%
    \begin{tabularx}{\dimexpr\linewidth-\ALG@thistlm}[t]{@{}X@{}}
        #1
    \end{tabularx}
}
\makeatother
% \usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{url}
\graphicspath{ {./images/} }
\renewcommand*{\Authand}{, }
\newcommand\NoDo{\renewcommand\ithmicdo{}}     % remove "do" from algs

\algnewcommand\algorithmicforeach{\textbf{for each}}
\algdef{S}[FOR]{ForEach}[1]{\algorithmicforeach\ #1\ \algorithmicdo}

\theoremstyle{definition}

%\newcommand{\basedir}{./appendix}
\makeatletter
\let\@fnsymbol\@arabic
\makeatother
\setlength{\parindent}{1.5em}
\setlength{\parskip}{1em}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.2}
%\usepackage{fancyhdr}
%\pagestyle{fancy}
%\fancyhf{}


\usepackage{hyperref}
\makeatletter

\newcommand*{\addFileDependency}[1]{% argument=file name and extension
\typeout{(#1)}% latexmk will find this if $recorder=0
% however, in that case, it will ignore #1 if it is a .aux or 
% .pdf file etc and it exists! If it doesn't exist, it will appear 
% in the list of dependents regardless)
%
% Write the following if you want it to appear in \listfiles 
% --- although not really necessary and latexmk doesn't use this
%
\@addtofilelist{#1}
%
% latexmk will find this message if #1 doesn't exist (yet)
\IfFileExists{#1}{}{\typeout{No file #1.}}
}\makeatother

\newcommand*{\myexternaldocument}[1]{%
\externaldocument{#1}%
\addFileDependency{#1.tex}%
\addFileDependency{#1.aux}%
}
%------------End of helper code--------------

% put all the external documents here!
\myexternaldocument{z_appendix}
```

Comment: Are you supplying your appendix as a separate `.tex` file to be compiled independently and then appended? This would be expected behaviour unfortunately per https://info.arxiv.org/help/submit_tex.html#how-to-include-supplemental-material

Comment: @DaiBowen Yes doing that, the current pdf generated includes the appendix

Comment: you must load xr-hyper before hyperref if you want links. (this will change in the next version, but won't help you in a texlive 2020). You could try `\RequirePackage{xr-hyper}` before documentclass if you can't move it in the preamble.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer The error goes when I do that, but the links still aren't clickable. The only other warning I get is: `LaTeX Warning: Command \@footnotemark has changed.
Check if current package is valid.` But I think that think's relevant

Comment: well sorry but without a minimal example it is quite impossible to debug this.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer added the raw logs and my latex set-up

Comment: that is neither minimal nor an example. Add some citations and also the content of the external aux-file. And try to shorten that , don't dump simply your code onto people that offer their help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is unfortunate but expected behaviour (see the note at https://info.arxiv.org/help/submit_tex.html#how-to-include-supplemental-material) when supplying multiple `.tex` documents to the arXiv compiler to be compiled independently with `pdflatex` (`latex` is handled differently).
The arXiv compiler then uses `pdfpages` which does not preserve working hyperlinks in the two documents.
All hyperlinks are affected and the problem will present without `xr-hyper`.

There are some workarounds given in [Merging multiple pdf files without breaking hyperlinks](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/497624/106162) but I'm not sure any of these will be usable while still having arXiv generate the individual PDFs.

Depending on your needs and aims, you could merge the full tex documents to maintain links, or supply the supplement as a PDF as an [ancillary file](https://info.arxiv.org/help/ancillary_files.html)

You can see the issue locally with

- `main.tex`

  ```
  \documentclass{article}
  \pdfoutput=1
  \usepackage{hyperref}

  \begin{document}
  \section{Foo}\label{foo}
  \clearpage
  \section{Bar}
  \ref{foo}
  \end{document}
  ```
- `supp.tex`

  ```
  \documentclass{article}
  \pdfoutput=1
  \usepackage{hyperref}

  \begin{document}
  zzz
  \end{document}
  ```
- `pdfpages.tex`

  ```
  \documentclass{article}
  \pdfoutput=1
  \usepackage{pdfpages}
  \usepackage{hyperref}

  \begin{document}
  \includepdf[pages=-]{main}
  \includepdf[pages=-]{supp}
  \end{document}
  ```

Comment: I added the appendix to the same tex document. Not ideal, but it fixed it. Thanks so much for highlighting the issue, saved me so much time!

Comment: even without the pdfpages use you wouldn't get links to external references (citations, other links work), there is no support for it currently in hyperref or xr-hyper.

Comment: Note that this is limited to pdflatex submissions only. Latex submissions which use a `dvips` compilation are assembled through ghostscript at the end of compilation and will have their links work.